Copy to UIPasteboard not working from Widget (AppIntent) button
I am trying to create a copy button for an iOS Widget using AppIntent.
Here is my code:
struct CopyTextIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Copy Resource"
    
    static var isDiscoverable: Bool { false }
    
    var resource: String
    
    init(resource: String) {
        self.resource = resource
    }
    
    init() {
        self.resource = "\'_'/"
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some ReturnsValue<String> {
        let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.string = resource
        
        return .result(value: resource)
    }
}

When I use this on my widget and click on it, it either silently fails or throws this error:

saving pasteboard failed with error: Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=11 "The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pasteboard name com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not valid.}

I am trying to copy my widget's string to UIPasteboard but it isn't working.

same with me dude, do u have any solution?
